# Measuring performance of clients

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm currently researching any ways to gather some analytics/metrics on the performance of client machines to our webapp. The app is heavily ajax and we are hoping to gather some stats about how well the clients machines are running it.

We don't necessarily want to put performance monitoring code all through the application (for a great number of reasons this may not be feasible anyways). Rather we would like to be able to run some kind of test or something when a user submits feedback that could give us an idea of how well their browser/computer performs.

This has been a slightly tricky thing to research as it keeps bringing up discussions about profiling etc. This is obviously useful but only to a point as our development machines are massively overpowered. We are hoping to get some metrics on the kinds of machines our clients are connecting with.

Does any kind of library/framework or best practice exist for this? So far my best though is to run some kind of CPU intensive process through JS for a few seconds and measure the performance that way ...

Thoughts or suggestions? May be an interesting discussion.

Comment: Not enough to be an answer: We create vm's for this purpose. Limit it to 1 cpu and 512mb and 'that crappy browser version the client still seems to use' Then just get a feeling of how it reacts. It's easy to setup and I think you should force developers to frequently look at their work from that end-users viewpoint.

Comment: @Eddy: not to forget the dial-up-like bandwidth

Comment: Not sure how well it would work (if at all) in a VM, but I have had good luck with dummynet (http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/) for throttling the network connection when doing client testing.

Answer (score 2):

here is what we do to monitor and analyze client usage data...

- use [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) to capture information about user (platforms, browsers, connection speeds, site usage, etc)
- use [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools) to get additional site stats and optimization suggestions
- use [Pagespeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/) plugin to analyze/fine tune high volume and/or slow pages
- use [Apache AB](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) or [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) - to run basic load tests against high volume pages

Comment: Another tool that's useful: Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) with the the neXpert performance addon (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/addons/neXpert.asp).

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question as you brought up most developer profile on their machines. I am not sure if there is any other way other than putting performance profiler in your code. The interesting part that you brought up that this is based on the user's feedback and not necessarily be sent all the time to the server.

We could develop a Profiler javascript class that basically collects:

- Function name
- Network round trip time
- Total Function execution time
- UserMachineProcessingTime = Total function execution time-network round trip
- Other useful info (similar to what YSlow or similar tools provides)

As you mention that his is based on the user feedback, we don't need to send this information all the time as each function gets called (which makes the app very chatty). We then aggregate this information on the client's side and possibly store it somewhere (maybe using HTML5 local storage?)

Only when the user give their consent to submit the performance profile, then we send this information to the server where you get the needed data. It would be interesting too to see how the user's react if we how a tiny message saying "We notice that your performance is below our average users' performance. Would you like to send your performance profile so we could learn and make it better?" (Different wording necessary, I am bad with this, but that is basically the message). Upon saying yes, the Profile send out the aggregate information that it has collected + additional information that Javascript could collect (user agent, etc). Off course the question is how many users would opt in to send their profile info, but it is one approach that we could try.

Comment: Yea it is an interesting discussing. Sadly we can't instrument a lot of the code with profiling because it is largely a pre-purchased package that we have customized. Also I'm a little worried that having profiling running constantly may degrade performance, especially in those cases that we really are interested in: people with terrible computers. I'm hoping to come up with some kind of relatively short test that could be run in the background while at the 'feedback section' that could get a basic idea of a client's performance.